# recvfrom returns -1 However WSAGetLastError() returns 0

Tags: windows, sockets, udp

During receiving of data from UDP socket while the remote socket was closed, Ideally it should returns the "ICMP Destination Host Unreachable" data.

I tested the same on windows 7 Operating System and the application built on VC2010.

Whenever the FD_READ event set and the recvfrom() function was called, then it returns SOCKET_ERROR and WSAGetLastError() returns error code as 0 which means that "Operation is completed successfully", however it should either returns error code as "WSAECONNRESET" or should read the ICMP data successfully.

Please suggest how to get rid out of it.

Answer (score 1):

There are several mistakes here.

1. Reading from a UDP socket whose peer has closed should block indefinitely or time out.
2. There are no RST packets or ECONNRESETs in UDP: this is a TCP phenomenon.
3. 'Destination unreachable' doesn't occur when trying to receive, only when sending. UDP is a connectionless protocol: there is no inherent awareness of the peer being closed when reading.

Answer (score 1):

You are wrong (probably thinking in terms of TCP) - the remote end does not communicate that its UDP socket was closed in any way. ICMP response is only generated if you *send* something to the remote end that does not have particular port bound.